# Incorrect syntax near '=' stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to alter the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertID] 
    @ID_EMP CHAR(11) = '91118800011', 
    @id_station tinyint = 1
as
    declare @status tinyint
    declare @comidaid int
    declare @empid bigint
    declare @fecha datetime
    declare @commerceid varchar(10)
    declare @isActive varchar(1)
    declare @isRestricted varchar(1)
    declare @resultado VARCHAR(50)

    if (Isnumeric(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ID_EMP,' ',''),'T-',''), 'C', '')) = 1)
    begin
        set @fecha = getdate()
        set @comidaid = database.tableName3(@fecha)
        --set @empid=cast(substring(@ID_EMP,3,6)as int)
        set @commerceid = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ID_EMP,' ',''),'T-',''), 'C', '')--@ID_EMP
        set @empid = CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@ID_EMP,' ',''),'T-',''), 'C', '') AS BIGINT)

        IF EXISTS(SELECT (@IsActive = CB_ACTIVO) 
                  FROM database.tableName  
                  WHERE (cb_codigo = @commerceid))
        BEGIN
            SET @resultado = 'Work'
        END

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT @IsActive = CB_ACTIVO 
                       FROM database.tableName  
                       WHERE cb_codigo = @commerceid)
        BEGIN
            SET @resultado = 'Work and user not exists'

            IF EXISTS (SELECT EmpId 
                       FROM database.tableName2  
                       WHERE empid = @commerceid)
            BEGIN
                SET @resultado = 'Work'
            END
        END
    END
```

This stored procedure works perfectly until I add this code:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT (@IsActive = CB_ACTIVO) 
          FROM database.tableName  
          WHERE (cb_codigo = @commerceid))
BEGIN
    SET @resultado = 'Work'
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT @IsActive = CB_ACTIVO 
               FROM database.tableName  
               WHERE cb_codigo = @commerceid)
BEGIN
    SET @resultado = 'Work and user not exists'

    IF EXISTS (SELECT EmpId 
               FROM database.tableName2  
               WHERE empid = @commerceid)
    BEGIN
        SET @resultado = 'Work'
    END
end
```

When I try to add these lines I get the following error message:

> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertID, Line 33
>   Line 33: Incorrect syntax near '='.
>
> Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Procedure InsertID, Line 37
>   Line 37: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Line 33 and line 37 correspond to the following statements:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT (@IsActive = CB_ACTIVO) FROM database.tableName WHERE (cb_codigo = @commerceid))

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT @IsActive = CB_ACTIVO FROM database.tableName WHERE cb_codigo = @commerceid)
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it?

PS: when I try all the If exists/not exists statements works fine, the problem is when I try to add them to the stored procedure.

Comment: You can't set a value in an `EXISTS` statement, as no data is actually returned.  `EXISTS` simply checks to see if a result is found or not.  I'm not sure what your intent is with the code, but it looks like you'll want to move that `SELECT` statement out to set the value, then do an `IF` statement on that variable checking its value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using these instead.

```
SELECT (@IsActive = CB_ACTIVO) FROM  database.tableName  where (cb_codigo =@commerceid)

IF (@isActive IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @resultado = 'Work'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @resultado = 'Work and user not exists'
    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  database.tableName2  where empid = @commerceid) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @resultado = 'Work'
    END
END
```